# Merging multiple rewrite rules in one

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a lot of the following redirects and I would really apreciate it if someone could give me 1 rewrite rule to cover them all...

```
Redirect 301 /coupons/company1.com/ http://www.website.nl/coupons/company1-com/

Redirect 301 /coupons/company3.net/ http://www.website.nl/coupons/company3-net/
```

I have the following but it ignores the /coupons/ folder:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)\.(nl|com|be|de)$ $1-$2 [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of all the rules shown you can use this single rule:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^/]+)/(.+?)\.(nl|com|be|de|net)/ http://www.website.nl/$1/$2-$3/
```

Comment: Awesome! How can I make this a 301 redirect? And is this better than a rewrite rule?